# How to import CSV file to MongoDB on Windows?

Tags: mongodb, csv

The mongoshell shows the result of the `mongoimport` command while trying to import a CSV file into MongoDB:

[image]

I wanted to import a csv file into MongoDB. So I have used the command:

```
mongoimport -d dbname -c collectionname --type csv --file filename.csv --headerline
```

after executing this command I constantly got an error of `missing ; before statement`. I stored the file in the path `mongo\bin` only. Is the command itself wrong or should I save the file any other location than I have saved it now? Can anyone give a way to fix this command?

Comment: mongoimport runs from os shell not from mongo shell. so exit shell and launch mongo import.

Answer (score 9):

[mongoimport](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/program/mongoimport/) is a binary that runs from OS shell and not the mongo shell.

So

```
C:\User\Home>mongoimport -d dbname -c collectionname --type csv --file filename.csv --headerline
```

is correct while

```
mongo> mongoimport -d dbname -c collectionname --type csv --file filename.csv --headerline
```

is not.